# Given quartiles, how do I draw a box-whisker using MATLAB, matplotlib, gnuplot, or some other package?

Tags: matlab, graph, matplotlib, statistics, gnuplot

I'm given a number of data points like this:

```
2.50%   3.45
25.00%  4.19
50.00%  4.7
75.00%  5.42
97.50%  6.87
```

This defines a complete box-whisker element for a plot. I'm not sure how I can plot this. All the methods I've looked up so far ([MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html), [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot), [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_canvas/boxplot.html)) construct boxes from the original data. I don't have access to the original data, but I do have all the information I *should* need to draw the boxes.

What's the best way to draw the boxes/whiskers without the data?

Comment: This PR https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2643 adds an easy way to do this in matplotlib.

Comment: This honestly would be ideal. Any idea when it'll get accepted?

Comment: Soon(TM) ;).  Seriously, before the 1.4 release, but that is still a while off.  If you want this _now_ checkout that branch and install from source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following trick in Matlab:

Let `x` be a vector containing your percentile values:

```
x = [3.45 4.19 4.7 5.42 6.87];
```

Let's extend this vector by repeating the median, appending it to the end:

```
y = [x x((1+end)/2)];
```

Now the 75, 50 and 25 percentiles of `y`, *considered as a data vector*, coincide with the desired values:

```
>>prctile(y,75)
ans =
    5.4200
>>prctile(y,50)
ans =
    4.7000
>>prctile(y,25)
ans =
    4.1900
```

So: simply call [`boxplot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/boxplot.html) using this extended vector as data:

```
boxplot([x x((1+end)/2)])
```

[image]

A nice thing of this approach is that you can use all the fancy [options](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/boxplot.html) of `boxplot` to customize the plot.

The trick can probably be applied to matplotlib and gnuplot as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Luis for you help. However I think that you post does not completely answer the question.

Even though your method works fine for the 25th and 75th percentiles it does not seem to work for 97.5th percentile.

For example considering the case:

```
x = [3.45 4.19 4.7 5.42 10];
y = [x x((1+end)/2)];
```

We correctly get:

```
>> prctile(y,75)
ans =
    5.4200
>> prctile(y,97.5)
ans =
    10
```

but when we plot the boxes/whiskers the 97.5th percentile is treated as outlier according to [matlab](http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283064). 
[image]

In order to fix this issue we should force the 97.5th percentile in this way:

```
p = prctile(y,97.5)
boxplot(y,'whisker',p)
```

[image]

Comment: I have this problem, but your solution causes an error.

Comment: the workflow is this: 1) compute the 97.5 percentile `p = prctile(y,97.5)` and then force it in the **boxplot** `boxplot(y,'whisker',p)`

Comment: I figured it was a typo and the help file for boxplot cleared it up. Thanks for your edit.